# What can I use to paste a list of URLs into a single field one entry at a time?

Tags: forms, automation, copy-paste

I need to paste a list of 50 URLs into the URL field on Amazon's infringement form (https://www.amazon.com/report/infringement), but the form only takes one URL at a time. Is there some program, macro, or programming tool that I could use to paste the list in automatically one by one with a short delay or by pressing a hotkey?

Comment: This page doesn't require captcha code, It is easy to send batch post form data to automate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a tool some options are Selenium or [borchief](http://www.botchief.com/) but if you are willing to develop then Cron + Python is another alternative. Cron would be used to schedule the script that you want to repetitively repeat. Using the mechanize module on python you can make a script that fills in a form on a website. Here are useful tutorial links for [cron](https://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-cron-jobs) and [mechanize on python](https://www.thetaranights.com/fill-online-form-using-python/). You could also just make another script that sleeps for some time before calling the mechanize script. There's also [HTMLunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for Java

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you could do with Selenium IDE https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Maybe start with something like this: https://nadimsaker.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-use-array-in-selenium-ide.html